# Getting issue in the length property of JSONPATH NReJSON(Redis) c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, redis, jsonpath

Below is my json string

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"first value","Added":"2022-06-15T09:48:36.7132436Z"},{"Id":2,"Name":"second value","Added":"2022-06-15T09:48:36.7132479Z"},{"Id":3,"Name":"third value","Added":"2022-06-15T09:48:36.713248Z"}]
```

And the structure is:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Added { get; set; }
}
```

In the redis, I have one key for which I am storing List.
In case to insert a single data record I was using length to store new data record and was using JSONPATH.

Below is the JSONPATH

```
var serializedRedisData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
_database.JsonSet(redisKey, serializedRedisData, ".[(@.length)]");
```

But getting below error:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: 'JSON Path error: path error: \n$.[(@.length)]\n^^^^^\n'
```

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

`@.length` is currently not supported in RedisJSON.
If you want to retrieve the last element you can use `$.[-1:]` instead.

But, it seems from your code that you're trying to push a new element to the end of the array. You should use `arrinsert` instead.

See: https://redis.io/commands/json.arrinsert/